# How to create an array from an array of objects by same key

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, mapping, reduce

I have an array of objects.
I want to merge the objects into a single array by same key. At that time, I also want to include other value in the array together.
It doesn't matter whether the merged array is an array or an object.

Current array:

```json
[
  {
    "datetime": "2022-01-10",
    "a": 0.5,
    "b": 80.6,
    "c": 1002.2
  },
  {
    "datetime": "2022-01-11",
    "a": 0.7,
    "b": 80.4,
    "c": 1002.4
  },
  {
    "datetime": "2022-01-12",
    "a": 0.4,
    "b": 80.2,
    "c": 1002.3
  }
]
```

Expected result:

```json
[
  [
    ["2022-01-10", 0.5], ["2022-01-11", 0.7], ["2022-01-12", 0.4]
  ],
  [
    ["2022-01-10", 80.6], ["2022-01-11", 80.4], ["2022-01-12", 1002.4]
  ],
  [
    ["2022-01-10", 1002.2], ["2022-01-11", 1002.4], ["2022-01-12", 1002.3]
  ]
]
```

or

```json
{
  "a": [
    ["2022-01-10", 0.5], ["2022-01-11", 0.7], ["2022-01-12", 0.4]
  ],
  "b": [
    ["2022-01-10", 80.6], ["2022-01-11", 80.4], ["2022-01-12", 1002.4]
  ],
  "c": [
    ["2022-01-10", 1002.2], ["2022-01-11", 1002.4], ["2022-01-12", 1002.3]
  ]
}
```

I use `forEach()` and it works.
But I want to know if there are other ways.

```js
const foo = [[], [], []];
json.forEach((item) => {
  const [a, b, c] = foo;
  a.push([item.datetime, item.a]);
  b.push([item.datetime, item.b]);
  c.push([item.datetime, item.c]);
});
```

Comment: these could be helpful? [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850412/merge-javascript-objects-in-array-with-same-key) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60327038/create-a-new-array-from-object-with-same-keys)

Comment: How about other entries to each item where the keys are not limited to just `datetime `, `a`, `b` and `c`?

Comment: @ishikawa ... Does the OP still participate in this thread?

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce function where the initial value will be an empty object.
after that, you can check if that object contains that particular key or not and push the data accordingly

```js
a = [
  {
    datetime: "2022-01-10",
    a: 0.5,
    b: 80.6,
    c: 1002.2,
  },
  {
    datetime: "2022-01-11",
    a: 0.7,
    b: 80.4,
    c: 1002.4,
  },
  {
    datetime: "2022-01-12",
    a: 0.4,
    b: 80.2,
    c: 1002.3,
  },
];

const solution = (key) => {
  return a.reduce((acc, { [key]: keyValue, ...next }) => {
    Object.entries(next).forEach(([dataKey, dataValue]) => {
      (acc[dataKey] ??= []).push([keyValue, dataValue]);
    });
    return acc;
  }, {});
};

console.log('Solution 1: ',Object.values(solution("datetime")));
console.log('Solution 2: ',solution("datetime"));
```

Comment: `const valueToReturn = { ...a };` ... is not necessary, even not from a *functional programming* point of view. One could just mutate the initially passed value as is and pass it again into the next iteration step of `reduce`.

Comment: ... and why would one use something like `const obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(next)); delete obj[key];` which fully stringifies and parses a datastructure if one could be more to the point with a precise destructuring? ... `a.reduce((result, { [key]: keyValue, ...data }) => { Object.entries(data).forEach(([dataKey, dataValue]) => (result[dataKey] ??= []).push([keyValue, dataValue]) ); return result; }, {});`

Comment: @PeterSeliger agreed with both points, thank you for review and help

Answer (score 1):

As for generic solutions (only the `datetime` property of each item needs to be known, thus the solutions are agnostic to all other properties) to both of the OP's use cases,

- the array of arrays where the nested array items are tuples of distinct `datetime` values and values of same item `key`s
- and the object of arrays where the arrays are the same but get referred to by `key`s which are distinct from `datetime`,

one easily could use the same [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) based approach only that

- for the latter result (object based `key` specific array of arrays) one passes an object as [initial value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#how_reduce_works_with_an_initial_value) and creates and aggregates the `key` specific nested arrays upon the currently processed `key` of each item's [rest-property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#rest_property) data-[`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries),
- whereas for the former result (array of arrays) the initial value is an array where one needs to create and/or access each key specific inner array by the current index of each of the rest-data's [`values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).

```js
const sampleData = [{
  datetime: "2022-01-10",
  a: 0.5,
  b: 80.6,
  c: 1002.2,
}, {
  datetime: "2022-01-11",
  a: 0.7,
  b: 80.4,
  c: 1002.4,
}, {
  datetime: "2022-01-12",
  a: 0.4,
  b: 80.2,
  c: 1002.3,
}];

console.log(

  sampleData
    .reduce((result, { datetime, ...rest }) => {
      Object
        .values(rest)
        .forEach((value, idx) =>
          (result[idx] ??= []).push([datetime, value])
        );
        return result;
    }, [])
);
console.log(

  sampleData
    .reduce((result, { datetime, ...rest }) => {
      Object
        .entries(rest)
        .forEach(([key, value]) =>
          (result[key] ??= []).push([datetime, value])
        );
        return result;
    }, {})
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

In case the [key (insertion) order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66279637/how-keep-the-order-of-items-in-an-object) of the original array items can not be guarantied amongst all items, one should use the `key`-specific second solution, where one would pass the created object to [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) in order to get an array of arrays ...

```js
const sampleData = [{
  datetime: "2022-01-10",
  a: 0.5,
  b: 80.6,
  c: 1002.2,
}, {
  datetime: "2022-01-11",
  a: 0.7,
  b: 80.4,
  c: 1002.4,
}, {
  datetime: "2022-01-12",
  a: 0.4,
  b: 80.2,
  c: 1002.3,
}];

console.log(

  Object
    .values(
      sampleData
        .reduce((result, { datetime, ...rest }) => {
          Object
            .entries(rest)
            .forEach(([key, value]) =>
              (result[key] ??= []).push([datetime, value])
            );
            return result;
        }, {})
    )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

See this it uses map and then returns an array just like your ist

```js
const data = [{
  datetime: "2022-01-10",
  a: 0.5,
  b: 80.6,
  c: 1002.2,
}, {
  datetime: "2022-01-11",
  a: 0.7,
  b: 80.4,
  c: 1002.4,
}, {
  datetime: "2022-01-12",
  a: 0.4,
  b: 80.2,
  c: 1002.3,
}];

const res = data.map((m ,_) => [
  [m.datetime,m.a],
  [m.datetime,m.b],
  [m.datetime,m.c],
]);
console.log({ res });
```

Or 2nd method because of comments

```js
const data = [{
  datetime: "2022-01-10",
  a: 0.5,
  b: 80.6,
  c: 1002.2,
}, {
  datetime: "2022-01-11",
  a: 0.7,
  b: 80.4,
  c: 1002.4,
}, {
  datetime: "2022-01-12",
  a: 0.4,
  b: 80.2,
  c: 1002.3,
}];

const res = ["a","b","c"].map(key => data.map(obj => [
  obj.datetime,
  obj[key],
]));
console.log({ res });
```

Comment: The result of this approach is not matching the shown in the question.

Comment: What does mean that

Comment: compare what is expected (shown in the question) and what your code produces.

Comment: But i have seen this its equivalent to the first expected output

Comment: I have added 2nd method now

Comment: Now both are one line functions

Comment: What I meant is that your first method produces `[ [ [dt, a], [dt, b], [dt, c] ], [ [dt, a], [dt, b], [dt, c] ], [ [dt, a], [dt, b], [dt, c] ] ]` instead of `[ [ [dt, a], [dt, a], [dt, a] ], [ [dt, b], [dt, b], [dt, b] ], [ [dt, c], [dt, c], [dt, c] ] ]`. The second method produces the correct result but arrays depth 1 level deeper than needed.

Comment: @Skkk ... I edited the OP's example codes in order to get/test each result instantly. As *RAllen* already mentioned both results do not meet the OP's specification.

Comment: @Skkk ... _"Now both are one line functions"_ ... one-liners are mostly both, hard to read, thus difficult to maintain.

Comment: @PeterSeliger.  How to add that run button

Comment: @Skkk ... [answer on _>>I've been told to create a "runnable" example with "Stack Snippets". How do I do that?<<_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/2627243)

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript reduce to optimize this:

```
const data = temp.reduce((acc,{a,b,c,datetime})=>{
  const [first,second,third] = acc;
  first.push([datetime, a]);
  second.push([datetime, b]);
  third.push([datetime, c]);
  return acc;
},[[],[],[]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const Json = [
    {
        "datetime": "2022-01-10",
        "a": 0.5,
        "b": 80.6,
        "c": 1002.2
    },
    {
        "datetime": "2022-01-11",
        "a": 0.7,
        "b": 80.4,
        "c": 1002.4
    },
    {
        "datetime": "2022-01-12",
        "a": 0.4,
        "b": 80.2,
        "c": 1002.3
    }
]

const func = (arr, i) => {
    let result = [];
    const constants = ["a", "b", "c"];
    for (let index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
        result.push([arr[index].datetime, arr[index][`${constants[i]}`]]);
    }
    return result;
}

const result = Json.map((d, i) => {
    return func(Json, i);
});

console.log(result)
```